# Symfony 2.3 Updating the data like 6.000

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I have table with 2 col datatype double. my entity class is

```
/**
 * @var float
 */
private $lat;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $long;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $dateAdded;
/**
 * Set lat
 *
 * @param float $lat
 * @return LocationMst
 */
public function setLat($lat)
{
    $this->lat = $lat;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lat
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getLat()
{
    return $this->lat;
}

/**
 * Set long
 *
 * @param float $long
 * @return LocationMst
 */
public function setLong($long)
{
    $this->long = $long;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get long
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getLong()
{
    return $this->long;
}
```

when i am trying to update the data it is showing err
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
i am expeting it is object mapping issue ...

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'long' is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

To fix this issue,

```
**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`long`")
*/
private $long;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a different column name rather than adding the annotation (the fix @Ramesh mentions only works if you are using annotations - there isn't a way to fix this issue using yml files for mapping) (i.e 'lng')